# Spring TEST REST Controller (consumes/produces JSON) - No Database, Offline - using Mockito

Tags: spring, testing, rest, controller, mockito

This question is next to the question [I had asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9155527/spring-rest-controller-test-with-spring-test-mvc-framework). In this question I want to focus on ways of testing a **Spring based REST Controller**.

Currently, the way I have set-up my testing is - Use **spring-test-mvc** framework with database that basically does **end-to-end testing**.

I want to get rid of a database layer. Why? Do I really need a database layer? Can't I mock a database?

So, I would like to know of an **efficient** way of testing a Spring based REST Controller which incorporates framework like **Mockito**, etc.

Please share and guide me in the right direction.

Comment: Mock (or stub/fake) your services.

Comment: So, what you are saying is - we can replace the database layer by mocking Services. And it's a good practice? Is it safe in terms of complete and guaranteed testing?

Comment: Is as complete and guaranteed as you make it--controllers should talk to services, services should talk to the DB. If you're testing your controllers, you only need to mock/stub service interactions.

Comment: @DaveNewton - if you write those two comments as an answer, I will upvote it.

Comment: @DavidWallace Done, and expanded--hopefully not too much, and not worse than my terse comments :)

Answer (score 4):

Generally, controllers only interact with services. Most controller/service interactions are data and/or status marshalling. (And exception handling.) Mocking/stubbing *(stucking?)* the service layer allows us to ensure the controller handles anything that might happen between it and its services.

"Complete and guaranteed" is up to you. For example, a service that interacts with a `User` database will probably only do a few things: retrieve a user, retrieve a list of users, update a user, or throw an application- or framework-specific exception. From the *controller's* point of view, those are the things that need to be tested--that's not that much stuff, so "completeness" is fairly straight-forward.

None of that tests the services or DAOs. Services, for example, might be tested using *"stucked"* DAOs. DAOs might be tested with an in-memory DB (although to be honest, I don't always test DAOs unless they have non-trivial, developer-generated SQL).

None of that is a replacement for integration testing, which can test routing, error and exceptional-condition handling, data formatting and content, and so on.